# For developing a website with Django, how can I use 'localhost' as a functioning SMTP server?

Tags: django, email

I'm developing a website with Django, and I'm currently working on the whole authentication setup, specifically the part where the user can use a password reset form that sends a one-time email with a link to use for resetting the password. However, if I try to use 'localhost' (currently my own personal machine) to send the email, the web server included with Django crashes with the message:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I did some research and figured out that to send email, I need to connect with an SMTP server, and my machine is apparently not an SMTP server. At least, not usually. Now, I want to note two things:

1. I am aware that I can use Gmail's SMTP servers, and in fact, I have code in another program that does just that. However, I would prefer to use 'localhost' if possible. If I can't, then I'll just create another Gmail account and use that.
2. I am aware that Django provides several email backends, and in fact, I currently have the file-based backend implemented right now. That's good enough to test the provided links and verify that they work, but I would like to *see* what the email would actually look like, with any formatting included in the email template.

So, **how can I turn 'localhost' into an SMTP server, and one that Django will accept?** Alternatively, if I can't, then please let me know and I will take the alternate route of setting up another Gmail account to use.

Comment: "the web server included with Django" --> 1) do you have control of that specific machine? 2) do you have a mailserver installed/configured on that specific machine?

Comment: 1) I'm using my own machine for development and testing, but I do plan on deploying it on another machine at some point in the future. So, yes, I have control. 2) I'm pretty sure I don't.

Comment: how about using `console` as the backend in the settings? The html text is printed on the console andyou can use that for testing.

Comment: @karthikr: Considered that, but 1) I can't click on the link in the console, and 2) it'd be nice to be able to *show* someone else what it looks like/will look like.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Ok, that `ConnectionRefusedError` makes sense then; Django is trying probably to connect to `localhost:25`, and since you don't actually have a mailserver running, there's nothing for Django to connect to. You'll have to [find some mailserver software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers), install it, and configure it.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman ...if you aren't too familiar with SMTP/mailservers in general, though, setting one up yourself *might* be tough. Good luck though!

Comment: @admdrew: Thanks for the link. Yeah, I've never set up a mail server before, but now is as good a time as any to learn how! :)

Comment: You can create a free account on sendgrid or mailgun and send your test email from there. Seems easier to me than to create a G account, validating it through SMS phone verification, etc. Sending email form your local dev machine is tough: many ISP block outgoing connections on the SMTP port and if it's not, your email will most certainly get rejected as SPAM.

Comment: @Tiago: Many thanks for suggesting mailgun! That works great for me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interest of potentially helping anyone who has the same issue and comes across this question, I'll share the path I chose.

As per [Tiago's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105779/for-developing-a-website-with-django-how-can-i-use-localhost-as-a-functioning#comment40914584_26105779),

> You can create a free account on sendgrid or mailgun and send your test email from there.

I took a look at sendgrid, but they require a website, and I don't have one (yet) as I am running the website locally on my machine. mailgun was much more useful, and they even provide code snippets to use in a variety of languages. However, as I am currently using Django's built-in views, I didn't use the snippets they provided. Rather, in my `settings.py` file, I set the following:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mailgun.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'postmaster@sandbox[sandboxID].mailgun.org'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '[Default Password]'
```

`sandboxID` and `Default Password` can be found by going to `https://mailgun.com/cp/domains/` and then following the link(s) to the page for whichever sandbox(es) has/have been assigned to you.

I tested this code and it worked great!

**Important note:** Apparently, it seems like you have to have your mailgun control panel open in a browser page in order to send mail from your sandbox(es). After I had closed that tab, I wasn't getting any mail, and it popped up in my Gmail inbox the moment I opened it back up.

Comment: Glad to help and thanks for taking your time writing what you ended up doing.